# How to call multiple methods of a class in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have a class (called name) which has different methods as follows:

alex(), john(), claire(), charles(), luke(), richard(), jen(), and so on

I need to call all these methods one by one, such as:

```
name.alex()
name.john()
name.claire()
name.charles()
name.luke()
name.richard()
name.jen()
```

... and so on

what I tried doing is creating a list of names, and call all the methods in a loop

```
names_list = ['alex', 'john, 'claire', 'charles', 'luke', 'richard', 'jen']

for i in range(len(names_list)):
    class_name.names_list[i]()
```

but this way of calling methods is failing. Is there a way to call multiple methods of same class in a loop?

Comment: Depending on what these functions are actually doing, it may make more sense to refactor your functions into a single one like `class_name.process_name('alex') # etc`.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Store the actual methods:

```
name = YourClass()
methods = [name.alex,  name.john, name.claire ] # ...

for m in methods:
    m()
```

My guess is that you have an [xy-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - what you want to do is problably trying to solve a problem that you could avoid using some other kind of design.

It is kindof impractical to have 1 method per name, for roughly approximated some million names...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it that way, you can use `getattr`:

```
names_list = ['alex', 'john', 'claire', 'charles', 'luke', 'richard', 'jen']

for name in names_list:
    getattr(class_name, name)()
```

Note that this assumes that `class_name` is an actual instance of your class, or that those methods are `staticmethods`. Otherwise, you will need `class_name()`.

Comment: It worked, now people just add their methods in the names_list and the methods they've created runs. Thanks!

Comment: @calvin that said, I would really advise you to see if you can rethink your class's design - that is a bit of an unconventional way to structure things.

Comment: I understand, but classes are predefined and are a part of library used internally within the org. I can't make any changes to that as I have no control over that library. Thanks!

Comment: @calvin you're welcome! If my answer helped you, you can accept it so that others who encounter this problem can see that it has a solution.